# Trying to generate 1000 random numbers btwn 1 and 100, inclusive from random generator using getrandom, isOdd,update, display

Tags: python

> For each value returned from the random generator, keep a count of the number of even numbers generated and the number of odd numbers generated.

I have tried and completed this code before, however, I received a zero for all my code being in "main." I am struggling using the four functions I mentioned in my title. I have started my new code using these functions but I'm quite lost, any help would be much appreciated.

This is what I have:

```
import random

def getrandom():
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    return x
    

def isOdd(f):
    if f % 2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def main():
    print("Random number generator")


for i in range(0,1000):
    x = getrandom()
    f = isOdd(x)
    import random


main()
```

Example teacher gave me:

The Even/Odd Challenge

Generating random numbers.....

After randomly generating 1000 numbers between 1 and 100:

The number of odd numbers:  524
The number of even numbers:  476

End of program.

Comment: Please show us the code where you tried to solve it.

Comment: You never keep count of the odd and even numbers. Why do you expect it to tell you the count?

Comment: My professor told me you can keep count of Odd and Even numbers using the isOdd(): function. I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to store the count of either odd numbers or the even numbers e.g.

```
import random


def get_random():
    return random.randint(1, 100)


def is_odd(f):
    return f % 2 == 0


odd_count = 0
for i in range(0, 1000):
    n = get_random();
    print(n)
    if is_odd(get_random()):
        odd_count += 1

print(f'No of odd numbers: {odd_count}')
print(f'No of odd numbers: {1000 - odd_count}')
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
...
...
...
23
3
63
No of odd numbers: 487
No of odd numbers: 513
```

Comment: Thank you so much Arvind. Do you or anyone know how to display 1000 numbers between 1-100 using the functions in my title? I am very confused and any help would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: @Dalton - You just need to print the generated number before the `if` condition. I have anyway updated the answer to reflect this change. I suggest you understand it well and practice similar questions to master the basics.